# How to rosdep install dependencies of one package?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, ros-kinetic, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given a catkin workspace topology that looks like this...

```
/tmp/foobar_catkin_ws.Nxg25I
`-- src
    |-- bar
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- inc
    |   |   `-- bar
    |   |       `-- bar.hpp
    |   |-- package.xml
    |   `-- src
    |       `-- bar.cpp
    `-- foo
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- inc
        |   `-- foo
        |       `-- foo.hpp
        |-- package.xml
        `-- src
            `-- foo.cpp

9 directories, 8 files
```

...where `foo` depends on `bar`, how do I install the dependencies for `foo` but not `bar`?

I already know I can install the dependencies for all packages in a catkin workspace with

```
rosdep install \
    --from-path /tmp/foobar_catkin_ws.Nxg25I \
    --ignore-src
```

But this is too much for my purposes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326140/how-to-rosdep-install-dependencies-of-one-package?/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
Does this not work for you:

```
rosdep install \
    --from-path /tmp/foobar_catkin_ws.Nxg25I/foo \
    --ignore-src
```

It won't work if `bar` is a dependency of `foo` but otherwise seems to do what you ask.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-06-18**:
Assume that `foo` depends on `bar`; and yes, it doesn't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
Well that would have been good to include in your question.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-06-18**:
@gvdhoorn, fixed per your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bit ugly (and there is probably a combination of options that achieves the same effect), but the following `check`s only the dependencies of `foo`, not `bar`, but does recognise `bar` as a dependency of `foo`:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/tmp/foobar_catkin_ws.Nxg25I/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH \
  rosdep check -i foo
```

At least on my system.

None of the dependencies of `bar` will be `check`ed in this example. Normally that would result in a potentially non-building workspace, but I believe that is what you asked for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-06-18**:
I have some preliminary indications that I can duplicate your technique. If there is still no answer after I hone the scripts using this trick, I'll add whatever I have working. Thanks very much, @gvdhoorn.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
I have a feeling you're not giving us all the details, especially given your earlier questions. Without all pertinent information we cannot help you.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-06-18**:
@gvdhoorn, don't feel bad --- you've already helped so much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
I don't feel bad.

But I don't like [xy-problems](http://xyproblem.info/) either. I'm not saying this is one, but it's impossible to know with the minimum amount of information you provide.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-04**:
@rubicks: any updates?

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-07-08**:
Nothing that's better than what you have. I'm going to declare this one answered.